# can't find Single Product Woocommerce template missing

Tags: woocommerce

i am trying to edit the single-product template of my website but this file seems to be lost or hidden as i show you below:

[image]

As you can see on folder's root there are no such file neither in the other folders. So i found a plugin that tells me what template is the current page using (What The File) , so i go to my single product page and check and voila:

[image]

You see that there's a template called: taxonomy-product-cat.php but it's nowhere!

I have set my settings to show all hidden files but still i can find this template.

Can someone help me find it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is not in your current theme. It can be found in WooCommerce plugin.

Look here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/3.8.0/templates

Or read more about WooCommerce [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: i forgot to accept it as solution. I checked  the doc and yeees! thanks a lot!